# How can i change color to some tiles?

Tags: tiles

I read that it's not possibile to change the background color of the tiles. So i downloaded an app to change the icons. My problem is that that app doesn't change all my icons (so i have My App Of The Day, games and a pair of icons that aren't changed). I triend to download different apps, but i can't still change these icons. Is there a way to replace the icon with a new one that has the color of my theme? My phone is a Lumia 520 with WP8

Comment: Can you elaborate on which 'apps' you used?

Answer (score 1):

It is only possible to change the colour if the tile is transparent. Some applications primary and secondary tiles have specific colours and cannot be changed, for example an application may wish to keep their brand colours on the tile.

Comment: So, can't i change the complete icon in some way?

Comment: @AsAs No, the app either allows it or not.